# Command line to update an expo react native app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

While updating an expo react native app (for android), which command should I use?

```
expo publish
```

or

```
expo upload: android
```

In my case, I'm updating the app for the first time. After reading the related documents from expo guides (https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps/), (https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/), I couldn't figure out which one I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are finished with your app

You run `expo publish` to publish your app to the expo servers

After that you can run `android:build` and for example side load the app to your android phone - this will take some time because your build will be qued.

If you change something in your app (except the SDK version) you can commit changes with `expo publish` and it will be distributed to all users because expo works with OTA Updates (Over the Air Updates).  So thats what you need in your case to update the app!

Comment: In which case, expo upload: android should be used? @yeslamFaded

Comment: Well I never used this command but it seems that expo:upload is used to upload your app to the google play app store. https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps/

Comment: Hi,According to documentations provided by expo, if you use "expo publish" then it won't need any setup and straight away publish your app to their respective store's. Howeve if you use "expo upload:android" or "expo upload:ios" then you have various other arguments that you can pass as additional setup in order to upload app on store

Sources :
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/
https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps/